# How to store setInterval globally and efficiently in Node.js so I can clear it from any route from my API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

When new order is insert I need to distribute it to subscribers based on a time gap of 12 seconds.
For example: `A` will receive the order immediately, 12 seconds later it will be reached to `B`.

If someone picks the order, for example `B`, I need to stop the propagation to `C` and `D`.
If `B` rejects the order, I don't want to wait until the 12 seconds resolve, I want to immediately propagate the order to the next in turn (`C`).

What I have tried to do is to set a recursive function firing by the time the setTimeout is functioned. But I don't have any way to clear it or skip or restart the mechanism for the cases I described above.

If I could save the setTimeout/setInterval instance in a global variable that could allow me to manage it from other API routes.

But I am not sure at all if it's a good approach, since storing global variables in node can lead to problems.

Maybe I can store it via Redis or cache or something so it won't catch too much memory and wont get collided with another methods that stored globally?

Comment: could you show as atleast some code

Comment: Actually there is no code to provide for such a case, I ask if its possible to store setTimeout/setInterval in such a way that I can clear it from any where in the API without store it globally. Storing it globally can make many issues, just for example, if the server shuts down and back, the store is gone.